# Freya freezing in Parallels 11

Tags: virtualization

I'm running Parallels 11 with Freya and at least once every day or two my Freya VM will just freeze. The screen is non-responsive and programs I have running in the background are not responding over the network. Any ideas why this is happening? I'm desperate enough at this point that I'm trying out VMWare Fusion just to see if it behaves itself any better. But I would hate to pay for a second license.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a problem with Parallels being so old, I have Parallels 16 and I think it is now up to 17.